# Запрет на переход без нажатия кнопки

Tags: php

Казалось бы, тривиально:

```
 <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit_name'])
    {
         echo 'Yahoo!';
    }
    else
    {
         echo 'Drawn';
    }
 ?>
```

Но не тут-то было. При нажатии F5 (обновить) кнопка приходит всегда нажатой, даже если мы таковую и не нажимали вовсе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уже нашел решение данной проблемы. Обойти этот глюк можно вот таким вот нехитрым способом:

1. В форме добавляем элемент `<input type="hidden" value="" name="check" id="check">`
2. Добавляем следующий Js-kod:

   `document.getElementById("check").value="checked"`
3. В php-скрипте добавлям следующий код:

   `if(isset($_POST['check'])&&$_POST['check']==checked")`
   `// ....`
   `unset($_POST['check']);`
4. profit.

Ну или да, FLK, можно и тем способом поискать.

Comment: А если у человека Js будет отключен ? Таких мало, но все же. Наверно лучше действовать по принципу капчи, каждый раз генерируя уникальный id.

Comment: Не понимаю. Можете объяснить принцип еще раз? Для каждой страницы генерить уникальный Id или как?

Comment: Всё просто

    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['check']) && !isset($_SESSION['unic'])){
        $_SESSION['unic']=true;
        echo 'Yahoo!';
    }

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. Вы мне очень помогли.

Answer (score 2):

```
header("Location: ".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
```

Comment: а это к чему простите?

Comment: Это чтобы Post-запрос не отправлялся заново при обновлении страницы. Я чуть-чуть изменил его. Первый раз было не совсем верно.

Comment: А, ясно. Т.е. браузер будет думать что ему приходит новый документ, хотя на самом деле все тот же, а все из-за перенаправления по Location по тому же адресу, верно?

Comment: Именно так.

Answer (score 0):

где то это уже обсуждалось, причина в том что при нажатии f5 post запрос на некоторых браузерах отправляется повторно в полном объеме. чтобы предотвратить подобное, надо привязываться к сессии либо к чему нибудь постоянному (бд, файлу, cookies) и проверять на уникальность $_POST

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='1; URL='''>";
```